# Draw CGImageRef & CGBitmapContextRef on CGL context?

Tags: macos, opengl, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, cglayer

I am looking for a way to draw a CGImageref and CGBitmapContextRef on CGL Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw to a CGL context you need to setup an openGL texture from the CGImage. To do so you have to access the raw pixels of the image as described here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1509/_index.html

if you have those pixels it's just a matter of creating an openGL texture from those pixels. Just google for tutorials, you should find plenty, i.e:
http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse872/tutorial4.html